# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using TestProject in automating functional testing?

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, tools

I'm currently checking out the testproject for the possibility of using it as a tool in our automation testing (functional). Please help me decide if it fits our project by giving me the advantages and disadvantages of this tool based on your experiences.

Comment: Pros and cons in relation to what? Also, what's your context? Tools don't exist in a vacuum, your context is important in any assessement.

Answer (score 1):

**What is testproject?**

> Free Test Automation for All. Cloud Hosted, Community Powered.
> TestProject is a free end-to-end test automation platform for web,
> mobile, and API testing that’s supported by the #1 test automation
> community.

https://testproject.io/

**Benefits**

- In built reporting
- Supports use as a step recorder ( simple recorder like IDE ) and also allows to be used as an SDK ( a library )

**Small issue**

It is cloud based even if you use it as an SDK, you need internet access . But now AWS, Postman etc are market leaders and they are cloud based so a cloud based solution is not an limitation

Answer (score 0):

After acquiring TestProject in 2019, Tricentis pulled out the plug in 2022, TestProject is end of life now.

https://blog.testproject.io/2022/11/17/testproject-end-of-life-your-questions-answered/